# After installing 12.04, WiFi ask me for a pass every 2 seconds

Tags: wireless, drivers

I installed 12.04 and when I boot my computer, I connect to my WiFi and I put my password, all was good but in 2 seconds, it prompts me to enter a password. Internet works but for only 2 seconds, and not more.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the **Network Manager** applet from the top panel, click on **Edit Connections...**, click on the **Wireless** tab.

Select your wireless connection name and click **Edit**. Click on the **Wireless Security** tab.

Enter you password, tick available to all users.

Done.